# FilteredList contains elements but they won't appear in ListView

Tags: java, javafx

So, I am working on a Java program that can store list of students in TableView.
Also there are options to sort that TableView and to show only students with A grade in ListView that appears in new window.

First two options are working, but I have a problem with filtering ListView.
When I click on a button that should open a new window with filtered ListView, ListView is empty.

I don't know why is that happening.

I tried to initialize some test objects and store them in FilteredList that works fine, but when I store objects from TextField in FilteredList they actually are in List, but they are not appearing in ListView.

This is code from main controller (showAStudents method)

```
public void showAStudents() {
        Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.initOwner(anchorPane.getScene().getWindow());
        dialog.setTitle("A Students");
        dialog.setHeaderText("This is list of A Students");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("aStudents.fxml"));
        try {
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);

        dialog.showAndWait();
        AStudentsController aStudentsController = 
        fxmlLoader.getController();
        aStudentsController.filterAStudents(students);
}
```

This is code from AStudentsController(filter a students method)

```
public void filterAStudents(ObservableList<Student> students) {
        FilteredList<Student> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(students, 
        aStudentsPredicate);
        Iterator<Student> iterator = filteredList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next()); /* This println is showing 
                                                    correctly filteredList 
                                                    content */
        }

        listView.getItems().addAll(filteredList);
    }
```

This println in console is showing all the students with a grade in console but they don't appear in ListView.

Comment: Note that `showAndWait` will stop the thread from continuing until the dialog is closed. Since you have the call to `filterAStudents` after the call to `showAndWait` the method is only invoked after the dialog is closed (not very useful). Also, if you want the `ListView` to stay up-to-date then you need to _set_ the `items` to the `FilteredList` instead of just copying the elements over.

Comment: It is becouse of showAndWait. I repleced it with show and now it's working. Thanks for help!!!